# Removing mutltiple specific lines from a txt with Batch

Tags: parsing, batch-file, text, case-sensitive

I am trying to remove multiple lines from a text file that have been parsed out of a PDF.
What the file looks like:

```
word1
word2
word3
b
word4
word5
b
word6
B
b
word7
word8
word9
b
```

Now the results I am looking for:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
B (is an initial of a user and should remain)
word7
word8
word9
```

Issues:
I can't get the batch to be case sensitive and if I do somewhat get it working it will remove all the b's from the words.
I keep walking into issues trying to achieve this in batch. I have no example script because I did not make any progress. Does someone have a way to do this properly?
If possible, I would like to have it working 100% in batch with no dependencies, please.

Comment: Can you show us what code you had when it was removing all the b's? This will allow someone to see where you went wrong and suggest edits.

Answer (score 1):

Using `findstr`'s regular expression will help you here. To exclude all lowercase standalone `b`'s you can do:

```
(findstr /V /RC:"\<b\>" filename.txt)>output.txt
```

Or to find only the uppercase standalone `B`'s and no other text:

```
(findstr /RC:"\<B\>" filename.txt)>output.txt
```

Comment: will remove every line that contains a single `b` (anywhere). Will probably work for this usecase, but more secure would be `findstr /vx "b"`